# Magento 2 - Request sample for carts/mine (GET)

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I try to call the carts/mine GET route of the Magento 2 REST API, but it does not show a request sample in the [documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/).

[image]

It says "Returns information for the cart for a specified customer."

But how do I specify the customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`carts/mine` endpoint is returning the cart for current logged in user.

If you need get cart for any user, then you need to use `carts/{cartId}` endpoint (see https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.6-admin/tag/cartscartId#operation/GetV1CartsCartId)

Answer (score 0):

carts/mine endpoint is the Customer API and not Admin API.

To specify the customer you will need Authentication Token of that customer.

1. get token using endpoint - POST /V1/integration/customer/token

   curl -X POST "https://<host>/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -d '{"username":"customer@example.com", "password":"customer_password"}'

   Sample Response - asdf3hjklp5iuytre
2. Use that authentication token when calling carts/mine endpoint

   curl -X GET "https://<host>/rest/default/V1/carts/mine" -H "Authorization: Bearer asdf3hjklp5iuytre"

Checkout this link [Token-based authentication](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token/) more details like token lifetime and related configurations.